# Export certain range as pdf based on userform checkbox

Tags: excel, vba, loops, userform, export-to-pdf

I want to export the last range and as PDF.

I am using the following code in a userform with checkboxes:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim xSht As Worksheet
    Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xFolder As String
    Dim xYesorNo, I, xNum As Integer
    Dim xOutlookObj As Object
    Dim xEmailObj As Object
    Dim xUsedRng As Range
    Dim xArrShetts As Variant
    Dim xPDFNameAddress As String
    Dim xStr As String
    'xArrShetts = Array("test", "Sheet1", "Sheet2") 'Enter the sheet names you will send as pdf files enclosed with quotation marks and separate them with comma. Make sure there is no special characters such as \/:"*<>| in the file name.
    xArrShetts = sheetsArr(Me)
    
    For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
        If xSht.Name <> xArrShetts(I) Then
            MsgBox "Worksheet no found, exit operation:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & xArrShetts(I), vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    
    Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
        xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Check if file already exist
    xYesorNo = MsgBox("If same name files exist in the destination folder, number suffix will be added to the file name automatically to distinguish the duplicates" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Click Yes to continue, click No to cancel", _
    vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
    If xYesorNo <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
    
    For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
        Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
        
        xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & ".pdf"
        xNum = 1
        While Not (Dir(xStr, vbDirectory) = vbNullString)
            xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & "_" & xNum & ".pdf"
            xNum = xNum + 1
        Wend
        Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
            xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xStr, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
        End If
        xArrShetts(I) = xStr
    Next
    
    'Create Outlook email
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "????"
        For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
            .Attachments.Add xArrShetts(I)
        Next
        If DisplayEmail = False Then
            '.Send
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The code is to determine which worksheets has to be exported as a pdf.
At the same time I'll have to fill in the map where the PDFs can be stored.
After that the code starts an Outlook item and stores the PDFs as attachment.

```vb
Private Function sheetsArr(uF As UserForm) As Variant
    Dim c As MSForms.Control, strCBX As String, arrSh
    For Each c In uF.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If c.Value = True Then strCBX = strCBX & "," & c.Caption
        End If
    Next
    sheetsArr = Split(Mid(strCBX, 2), ",") 'Mid(strCBX, 2) eliminates the first string character (",")
End Function
```

The second code is to determine which worksheets are to be exported on the basis of the checkboxes with value true.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, try better explaining what "the last range" does mean...

Comment: I am using a document where i write  things down per period. so the doucment is getting longer and longer. for the export i use only the last period.

Comment: Still not so clear... How the code to determine this "last period"?

Comment: that's my question is this possible?

Comment: In order to answer your question, I must understand it... What does "down per period" mean? Is it there a cell in a specific column containing a time stamp, or something similar?

Comment: the file I send you earlier is a good example. each worksheet the range (A4:H27) gets copied en pasted 5 rows lower then the last row (27). Then i only want to export the last copied and pasted range.

Comment: I cannot start working if I do not understand what you mean... In your workbook, there is such a range. Only one. So, do yo copy that range and after that (probably) change some data. Should the code export the last 27 rows, starting from last  "AAN : " in column A:A?

Comment: It looks that between the row containing "AAN : " and the last one ("PRIJZEN IN EURO & EXCLUSIEF BTW.") there are only 23 rows. Can this number of rows be variable?

Comment: no It's a fixed range only the frist cell changes (AAN:)

Comment: OK I will adapt your code and paste an answer...

Comment: thanks for you anwser but i get the wrongcode: Worksheets not found

Comment: 1. When referring to my code, please answer below my answer. 2. This error should not  be related to the code I pasted... You should check how you named your ticked check boxes, or **I hope you did not replace the function** when pasted the new code... Please, try inserting the next code line `Debug.Print Join(xArrShetts, "|"): Stop` after `xArrShetts = sheetsArr(Me)`. What does it return in Immediate Window?

Comment: Still alive? Did you test the code as I suggested above? If yes, what does that code line return? Is it something you do  not understand? Immediate Window can be shown pressing `Ctrl + G`, being in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor)... When you do not understand something, please ask for clarifications.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I didn't Awnser to you, i tried to get it to work but when I ran the code nothing happend. I'll post my worksheet here, will you have a look for me? https://easyupload.io/vbyksw

Comment: After so many days I did not remember well what is it about... Please, copy the updated code over **all existing code** in the used user form. You should learn that using `Option Explicit` will not let you using wrong/not declared variables... [Here](https://easyupload.io/ur77og) the updated workbook.

Comment: It is difficult to understand how you do not have 10 seconds only to check if received an answer, when placing a question...

Comment: I am very sorry. this is not a hobby but work and i am very busy at the moment

Comment: I tested your file and it works but it doesn't put de range on a single A4 paperformat is that possible?

Comment: When did you ask about "put de range on a single A4 paperformat"? Do you imagine that we do not work and just wait for people asking questions? Meaning that we can wait for days and you do not have 10 seconds to check if somebody answer your question. Very interesting opinion...

Comment: I can't follow you sorry, but the quistion to put the range on a single A4 is new.

Comment: Did you place such a new question, as the community rules state?

Comment: If you will place such a question, please tag me here (@FaneDuru) and I will help you if I will be available. If not, somebody else will solve it. In the next half of hour I think I have some availability...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, replace all code in the used form module with the next one:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim xSht As Worksheet, xFileDlg As FileDialog, xFolder As String, xYesorNo, I, xNum As Integer
 Dim xOutlookObj As Object, xEmailObj As Object, xUsedRng As Range, xArrShetts As Variant
 Dim xPDFNameAddress As String, xStr As String, rngExp As Range, lastRng As Range
 
 xArrShetts = sheetsArr(Me) 'do not forget the keep the sheetsArr function...

 For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
    If xSht.Name <> xArrShetts(I) Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet no found, exit operation:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & xArrShetts(I), vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
    End If
 Next

 Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
    xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
 Else
    MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
    Exit Sub
 End If
 'Check if file already exist
 xYesorNo = MsgBox("If same name files exist in the destination folder, number suffix will be added to the file name automatically to distinguish the duplicates" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Click Yes to continue, click No to cancel", _
 vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
 If xYesorNo <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
 For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
    Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
    
    xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & ".pdf"
    xNum = 1
    While Not (Dir(xStr, vbDirectory) = vbNullString)
        xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & "_" & xNum & ".pdf"
        xNum = xNum + 1
    Wend
    Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
        Set lastRng = xSht.Range("A" & xSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)   'determine the last cell in A:A
        Set rngExp = xSht.Range(lastRng.Offset(-26), lastRng.Offset(, 7))  'create the range to be exported as pdf
        rngExp.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xStr, Quality:=xlQualityStandard 'export the range, not the sheet
    End If
    xArrShetts(I) = xStr
 Next

 'Create Outlook email
 Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
 With xEmailObj
    .Display
    .To = ""
    .cc = ""
    .Subject = "????"
    For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
        .Attachments.Add xArrShetts(I)
    Next
    If .DisplayEmail = False Then
        '.Send
    End If
 End With
End Sub

Private Function sheetsArr(uF As UserForm) As Variant
  Dim c As MSForms.Control, strCBX As String, arrSh
  For Each c In uF.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If c.Value = True Then strCBX = strCBX & "," & c.Caption
        End If
  Next
  sheetsArr = Split(Mid(strCBX, 2), ",") 'Mid(strCBX, 2) eliminates the first string character (",")
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   Unload Me
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.